# Sum function in haskell producing 'Non-exhaustive pattern' error

Tags: haskell

Here is an example of my code that is producing the error:

```
amount :: [Int, Int, Int] -> Int
amount [(a, b, c)] = sum( map getBalance [(a, b, c)])
                         where getBalance :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
                               getBalance (d, e, f) = f
amount [] = 0
```

Originally the code was just:

```
amount :: [Int, Int, Int] -> Int
amount [(a, b, c)] = sum [c]
```

But I tried rewriting and adding things to see if I could find the cause of the error, and I couldn't. I'm rather new to Haskell, so if it's a stupid error I apoligise.

Comment: Just as a stylistic thing, you *really* should write that as `sum (map getBalance [(a, b, c)])`. The parenthesis indicate a subexpression, not function application. They should be tight around that subexpression.

Comment: Well haskell is meant to be a beautiful language, so style is always useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type signature you've written describes a list of three Ints: `[Int, Int, Int]`. The list types have indeterminate length, however, and the amount function you've written seems to expect 3-tuples of Ints, which would be written as `[(Int, Int, Int)]`; this can be derived from the definition anyway. Loading the first code block into ghci therefore produced:

```
test.hs:1:11:
    Illegal type: '[Int, Int, Int]
```

The second error appears once I provide it with a longer list of input:

```
*Main> amount [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
*** Exception: test.hs:(2,1)-(5,13): Non-exhaustive patterns in function amount
```

The problem here is that neither of the patterns match: you have patterns for lists with one or zero entries, but not more. Seeing that `[(a, b, c)]` is a repeated expression, how about we just replace it?

```
amount [] = 0
amount xs = sum( map getBalance xs)
                     where getBalance :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
                           getBalance (d, e, f) = f
```

Now any length of list will be passed to `map`, which is fine, because it is meant to handle an arbitrary length. So is `sum`, actually, so we didn't even need to add the special case for an empty list.

If you want to add a pattern for the longer-than-one lists, the traditional form is `x:xs`, breaking it up into a head `x` and tail `xs`. That pattern doesn't match the empty list, because it cannot be split.

The problem with your original code was also that it only defined a version for a list of one tuple. We can use list comprehension or map to handle that:

```
amount1 abcs = sum [c | (a,b,c) <- abcs]
amount2 = sum . map (\(a,b,c) -> c)
```

All of these variants do the same thing, even though amount2 didn't even mention an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I actually had [(Int, Int, Int)] with my own defined types, and changed it for the post to make it easier to understand. Oops. But your answer was very helpful :).

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly. When [(a, b, c)] was on the left hand side of the function it viewed that as a list with one tuple element, rather than as a list of tuples? And in the solution it only acted on the list when it viewed it as a single variable with a list type?

Comment: Yes, in pattern matching [(a,b,c)] is a list of one 3-tuple, while in a type signature it means a list of (any number of) 3-tuples. The argument to map reconstructed an identical list, and longer lists weren't covered. The version with xs instead passes the same list, whatever the length, to map.

Answer (score 1):

First, your type signature is wrong, it has to be

```
amount :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int
```

The "Non-Exhaustive pattern Error occurs, because you provided only two cases of lists:
At the bottom the case for empty list [], and above the case, where the list holds one element 
(`[(a,b,c)]` is a list with the element `(a,b,c)`. Hence your code would work with `amount [(1,2,3)]`)

Easiest way: Replace `[(a,b,c)]` with `xs`, at the left of the = and the right.

Answer (score 0):

`(a,b,c)` is a tuple: `(a,b,c) = (,,) a b c`

```
amount :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int
amount [(a, b, c)] = ...
```

The right one

Answer (score 0):

I certainly wouldn't recommend to make `Int` a `Monoid` in "serious" code, but it *would* work:

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Monoid

amount :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> Int
amount xs = let (_,_,x) = F.fold xs in x 

instance Monoid Int where
  mempty = 0
  mappend = (+)
```